# MS Office shortcuts in start menu don't work on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office, windows

In Vista (Business), the shortcuts that are automatically added to the start menu (for recently run programs) don't work for MS Office programs. You click on them and nothing happens.

Has anyone seen this and been able to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can be caused by a third-party shell extension, which seems to only affect the Windows Installer shortcuts like Office shortcuts.

You could use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to resolve the problem.

Comment: Perfect! I was able to use ShellExView to find the exact extension causing this problem. Thanks!